# Scrolling text in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show scrolling/moving text in my web portal.Web portal is made of asp.net,C#,Sql.How to do that?Do I need to download any javascript file for this?How it is safe?Unable to see marquee control in my html control kit.

Comment: You should know that questions seeking a tool or library are offtopic in stackoverflow. Also share [mcve] of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to animate text back and forth across the screen:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>HTML 5 Animated Text</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var context;
        var text = "";
        var textDirection ="";

        $(function()
        {
            context = document.getElementById("cvs").getContext("2d");            
            setInterval("animate()", 30);

            textDirection ="right";
            textXpos = 5;
            text = "Animation!";    
        });  

        function animate() {            
            // Clear screen
            context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
            context.globalAlpha = 1;
            context.fillStyle = '#fff';
            context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);    

            var metrics = context.measureText(text);
            var textWidth = metrics.width;

            if (textDirection == "right") {
                textXpos += 10;

                if (textXpos > 500 - textWidth) {
                    textDirection = "left";
                }
            }
            else {
                textXpos -= 10;

                if (textXpos < 10) {
                    textDirection = "right";
                }                    
            }

            context.font = '20px _sans';
            context.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
            context.textBaseline = 'top';
            context.fillText  ( text, textXpos, 180);    
          }    
          </script>
      </head>
      <body> 
         <div id="page">
            <canvas id="cvs" width="500" height="500">
               Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
            </canvas>
         </div>
      </body>
   </html>
```

If you want to see this in action, please go to this fiddle-
 http://jsfiddle.net/bS79G/

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no `marquee` control in the kit, you can add it manually, by writing the code in the `.aspx` file.

Follow this url:[How to use marquee tag in ASP.Net](https://forums.asp.net/t/1916515.aspx?How%20to%20use%20marquee%20tag%20in%20ASP%20Netfor) for a better understanding. Hope this helps.

**Edit**

You might be using `Design View` instead of `Source View` in Visual Studio. Switch to the `Source View` , where you can write and modify the code. Have a look here:[Walkthrough: Basic HTML Editing in Visual Studio for Web Forms Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z74w20y(v=vs.110).aspx).